# How to present plot x-axis ranges in correct sort order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The below reproducible code generates a data stratification table, which can be viewed as either a table or plot depending on the user's selection via radio button (user also can select the period to stratify; I left in this functionality to show how the plot sorting issue persists but it does make the below code a bit longer...).

How can I modify the plot, so the x-axis ranges follow the same order as the ranges in the left-most column of the table? The ascending sort order in the table is correct, the plot sort order is not correct. The images at the bottom explain better.

I'm new to `ggplot()` and am having a hard time with it. I'm open to any other suggestions! I had to fiddle with `ggplot()` quite a bit to even get to this basic point and things do not look well done even to my novice eye (for example, going from `list()` to dataframe to matrix, doesn't seem optimal - but that's how I stumbled through and got this to work). For the bar plots I feel it's important to have the value labels appearing above the bars for readability, and will remove the y-axis labels on the left later.

Reproducible code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <-
  fluidPage(
    uiOutput("stratPeriod"),
    radioButtons(
      inputId = 'stratsView',
      label = NULL,
      choices = list("Table view" = 1,"Plot view" = 2),
      selected = 1,
      inline = TRUE
    ), 
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.stratsView == 1",h5(strong("Stratified data:")), tableOutput("stratData")),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.stratsView == 2",h5(strong("Stratified data:")), plotOutput("stratPlot"))
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      ID = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
      Period = c("2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04"),
      Values_1 = c(-6, 26, 36, 46, 56, 86, 100, 10, 20, 30)
    )  
  })
  
  output$stratPeriod <- renderUI({
    chc <- unique(na.omit(dat()[[2]]))
    selectInput(inputId = "stratPeriod", 
                label = "Choose point-in-time:",
                choices = chc,
                selected = chc[1])
  })
  
  stratData <- function(){
    req(input$stratPeriod)
    filter_exp1 <- parse(text=paste0("Period",  "==", "'",input$stratPeriod, "'"))
    dat_1 <- reactive({dat() %>% filter(eval(filter_exp1))})
    breaks <- seq(min(dat_1()[["Values_1"]]), max(dat_1()[["Values_1"]]), length.out = 6) 
    tmp <- dat() %>% 
      filter(eval(filter_exp1)) %>%
      mutate(Range = cut(!!sym("Values_1"), breaks=breaks, include.lowest=TRUE, right = TRUE, dig.lab = 5)) %>% 
      group_by(Range) 
    tmp <- tmp %>%
      summarise(Count = n(),Values = sum(!!sym("Values_1"))) %>%
      complete(Range, fill = list(Count = 0,Values = 0)) %>% 
      ungroup %>% 
      mutate(Count_pct = Count/sum(Count)*100, Values_pct = Values/sum(Values)*100) %>% 
      dplyr::select(everything(), Count, Count_pct, Values, Values_pct) %>%
      bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Total"))) %>%
      
      ### Reformat range characters: replace standard stratification notation of (#,#] with [# to #]
      mutate(Range = str_replace(Range, "^\\(", "[")) %>% 
      mutate(Range = str_replace(Range, "\\,", " to "))   
    
    Count <- tmp %>% pull(Count)
    Range <- tmp %>% pull(Range)
    list(data = tmp, 
         Range = Range[-length(Range)],
         Count = as.data.frame(Count[-length(Count)]))
  }
  
  output$stratData <- renderTable({stratData()$data})
  output$stratPlot <- 
    renderPlot({  
      x <- as.matrix(stratData()$Range)
      y <- as.matrix(stratData()$Count)
      ggplot(stratData()$Count,aes(x,y)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        geom_text(aes(y = y + sign(y)/4,label = y),
                  position = position_nudge(y = 0)
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Replace the `output$stratPlot <- renderPlot({...})` section above with the below to reflect the solution offered in Yacine's comment:

```
 output$stratPlot <- renderPlot({  
      
      x <- factor(stratData()$Range, levels = c(stratData()$Range)) # < solution involves this change
      
      y <- as.matrix(stratData()$Count)
      
      ggplot(stratData()$Count,aes(x,y)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        geom_text(aes(y = y + sign(y)/4,label = y),
                  position = position_nudge(y = 0)
        )
  })
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about you change the order of your variable upstream with `factor()` function?
Example: `x$Range <- factor(x$Range, levels = c("[-6 to 6.4]", "[6.4 to 18.8]", ...))`

Comment: While creating the data for plotting, you are removing the factor levels, as a result x-axis is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Inside the renderPlot({}), changing the x <- ... to x <- factor(stratData()$Range, levels = c(stratData()$Range)) appears to have solved the issue. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I researched "factors" as a result of your guidance.